# Pandas Dataframe Question: Subtract next row and add specific value if NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to groupby in pandas, then sort values and have a result column show what you need to add to get to the next row in the group, and if your are the end of the group. To replace the value with the number 3. Anyone have an idea how to do it?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'label': 'a a b c b c'.split(), 'Val': [2,6,6, 4,16, 8]})
df

label   Val
0   a   2
1   a   6
2   b   6
3   c   4
4   b   16
5   c   8
```

Id like the results as shown below, that you have to add 4 to 2 to get 6. So the groups are sorted. But if there is no next value in the group and NaN is added. To replace it with the value 3. I have shown below what the results should look like:

```
    label   Val Results
0   a   2   4.0
1   a   6   3.0
2   b   6   10.0
3   c   4   4.0
4   b   16  3.0
5   c   8   3.0
```

I tried this, and was thinking of shifting values up but the problem is that the labels aren't sorted.

```
df['Results'] = df.groupby('label').apply(lambda x: x - x.shift())`
df

label   Val Results
0   a   2   NaN
1   a   6   4.0
2   b   6   NaN
3   c   4   NaN
4   b   16  10.0
5   c   8   4.0
```

Hope someone can help:D!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use groupby, diff and abs:

```
df['Results'] = abs(df.groupby('label')['Val'].diff(-1)).fillna(3)

  label  Val  Results
0     a    2      4.0
1     a    6      3.0
2     b    6     10.0
3     c    4      4.0
4     b   16      3.0
5     c    8      3.0
```